# WPF class not found in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a key for a class to use in XAML, but Visual Studio 11 says that no such class exists.

Steps:

I created a class inside my program namespace:

```
namespace Test {
    public class PointCollectionConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter....
```

I added a local namespace reference in MainWindow.xaml

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeometryTest"
```

I try to add the class as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
      <local:PointCollectionConverter x:Key="pointCollectionConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Fixed after recompilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF - How to properly reference a class from XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523908/wpf-how-to-properly-reference-a-class-from-xaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace is `Test` and you use `GeometryTest`? Something's not right here.

How about:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
```

Comment: I changed the namespace for easier reading here. Turned out the I just needed to recompile it. But your answer was correct anyway :P

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: People seem to trust their IDEs too much; [a recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250925).