# Adding reference to a convertor defined inside a Class in XAML -Windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Here is my modal

```
 public class items
        {
            public string item_name { get; set; }
            public string item_id { get; set; }
            public string item_quantity { get; set; }
            public string unit_id { get; set; }
        }
 public class services
        {
            public List<items> items { get; set; }
        }
```

I am assigning an object of the above class as itemsource for my List.I need to display unit name , but since my object contains only unit id, Im retrieving it from dictionary and using a convertor to bind it.

I am unable to reference this convertor from XAML.As this convertor is not directly inside namespace and within another class.

```
Namespace myname
{
     public partial class write : PhoneApplicationPage
     {
         public static Dictionary<String, String> units1 = new Dictionary<String, String>();

 public write()
         public class UnitConvertor : IValueConverter
         {
                public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                    string text = value.ToString();
                    if (text != null)
                    {
                        String unit = units1[text];
                        return unit;
                    }

                    return value;
                }

                public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                    return value;
                }
            }

      }
}
```

XAML PAGE:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myname"
```

I am not able to reference it under `<Grid.resources>`

Comment: put your converter out side class and refer it. Why you wrote it inside constructor?.

Comment: Because I m using a Dictionary and I m unable to declare a dictionary directly under namespace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your namespace as `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myname.write"`

and you can access your `Converter` in the `local` namespace..

```
<Grid.resources>
    <local:UnitConvertor x:Key="unitConverter"/>
</Grid.resources>
```

Comment: I tried this way.. I get an error saying cant find UnitConvertor in namespace myname.write

Comment: Cant you keep the Converter in the namespace directly?

Comment: Im using a dictionary inside the convertor,I wasnt able to place the definition of dictionry inside Namespace directly..If there is a way..kindly let me know..

Comment: It was a static field na.. so you could access it directly with the class name right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397622/how-to-reference-a-sub-class-for-ivalueconverter -- Same thing done here... Have a look...